# Using custom hardware decoder with chromium browser?

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg, chromium, chromium-embedded

I am working on a custom hardware, where we are having a **hardware decoder**. This hardware decoder is working fine with linux applications and gstreamer. Now we are planning to extend hardware decoding support to chromium browser.

To the best of my knowledge, chromium browser is using **ffmpeg libraries** for demuxing and decoding.

So if I add our custom hardware decoder support to ffmpeg libraries, how would chromium browser will come to know to use our custom hardware decoder while playing videos ?

Note :- We have only one hardware decoder on our custom hardware.

Comment: Why should chromium or any other application know about it? If you add support for your hardware to ffmpeg, make it transparent.